# regex extract substrings matching a location in a given pattern

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a series of template strings which define variable substitutions with {}.  And the substitutions can take any characters, but the surrounding string is fixed.

```
# template string pattern
file{a}-{b}stuff.txt 

# final string after substitution
fileDR-v1.0stuff.txt
```

Given an example string, I want to be able to extract out which pieces are the variables that have been substituted. For example, given "fileDR-v1.0stuff.txt" it should return {'a': 'DR', 'b':'v1.0'}.  I can get it mostly working by creating a regex pattern out of the template by replacing all bracketed content with a regex group (.*) to capture all characters.

```
template = "file{a}-{b}stuff.txt"
example = "fileDR-v1.0stuff.txt"

# escape any periods in the pattern
subtemp = template.replace('.','\.')
# create the regex pattern
pattern = re.sub('{(.*?)}', '(.*)', subtemp)
print(pattern)
'file(.*)-(.*)stuff.txt'

# perform the search using the pattern on both the template and example 
pmatch = re.search(pattern, template)
tmatch = re.search(pattern, example)

pmatch.groups()
('{a}', '{b}')

tmatch.groups()
('DR', 'v1.0')
```

From the groups I can extract the keys and values and recreate the mapping of a='DR', b='v1.0'.  However, I'm having problems extracting the proper strings for templates that have brackets back to back.  Is there a correct syntax to handle these edge cases?

Example templates that I have

```
'{a}.{b}'
'{dr}Q/{dr}Q.fits'  
'parts_{dr}{version}_{sample}_{ns}.fits.gz'
'path/{ver}/{plate}/stack/file-{plate}-{ifu}-LOG.fits.gz'
```

And example strings

```
'mask.html'
'DR10Q/DR10Q.fits'
'parts_DR12v1.0_1_n.fits.gz'
'path/v2_4_3/8000/stack/file-8000-191-LOG.fits.gz'
```

My current pattern of (.*) and escaping `.` works for most cases.  If I run the above code on these 4 examples I get

```
('{a}', '{b}')
('mask', 'html')
---- 
('{dr}', '{dr}')
('DR10', 'DR10')
----
('{dr}{version}', '', '{sample}', '{ns}')
('DR12v1.0', '', '1', 'n')
----
('{ver}', '{plate}', '{plate}', '{ifu}')
('v2_4_3', '8000', '8000', '191')
----
```

What's the best way to handle cases like `{dr}{version}` or `{a}{b}`?  I know there's no real way regex can separate the two strings but are there other options?

Comment: Is `{pattern}` always an arbitrary string or could you define e.g. that `{dr}` will never straddle a slash or contain punctuation, for example? Of course, just using regex for the constraints directly would make this a lot simpler.

Comment: @tripleee `{pattern}` is always an arbitrary string.  Mostly.  It will always be a string that could consist of letters, numbers, and some symbols like `.`, `-`, or `_`.  But it won't contain most symbols.  The patterns will never have a slash since it would confuse the filepath definition, which is what these are for.  I don't have much control over the variable substitution and adding constraints to them.

Comment: Sounds like your problem isn't well-defined, then, regex or not. If you can come up with some disambiguation rules, a better regex could perhaps be devised. For example, if the patterns should always begin and end on alphanumerics, you could say something like `([a-z0-9](?:[^/]*[a-z0-9])?)` instead of `(.*)`

Comment: From your samples it *looks like* maybe we could say `{dr}` should always end with a number. But if we can't add constraints like that, what *can* we change?

Comment: Yes most variables used in the substitution will end on alphanumerics but there are no explicit rules set in place, beyond what will be limited by a standard posix filepath and name.  The variables will never contain anything to break that.  Some variables will be implicitly constrained, like `{dr}`, which will always end in a number.  But I also have other double bracket combinations, which use variables that also have some known constraints, but I can't make that assumption about every variable that people will use.  The variables names aren't set by any specific guidelines.

Comment: Well, if you cannot clarify any criteria for how to do these things, what sort of answer do you expect? Regex greedy matching prefers the longest leftmost match and if that's not what you want, you have to modify your regex.